# Is it possible to make a catch block that waits until the whole try block is executed?

Tags: java, parsing, exception, try-catch

## What I'm doing

I'm trying to make a cleaner version of nested try catch blocks and I'm solving a very basic exception problem while doing so. I'm making a calculator that will do great things. Before then however, it must take in user inputs as strings and convert them to either floats or integers. I'm doing this by simply calling the in built parseInt and parseFloat functions of java. Right now I'm using a nested try catch block to do this:

```
String stringToParse = "1.0"
try{Integer.parseInt(stringToParse);}
catch(NumberFormatException n){
    try{Float.parseFloat(stringToParse);}
    catch(NumberFormatException n){
        System.out.println(n)
        }
    }
```

## Why is that a problem?

This is messy to me and I'd rather have a try block that collects the errors but doesn't immediately go to the catch block, rather it executes the entire try and catches any errors after the try has been executed. I've made a runnable example of this myself that shows what I desire:

```
    String num = "1.0";
    int i = 0;
    ArrayList<Object> listofResults = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> listOfErrorIndices = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        listofResults.add(Integer.parseInt(num));
        i++;
        listofResults.add(Float.parseFloat(num));
        i++;
        listofResults.add(Integer.parseInt(num));
    } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
        listOfErrorIndices.add(i);
    }
    for (Integer element:listOfErrorIndices) {
        System.out.println(element);
        //this currently prints out 0 and I want it to print out both 0 and 
        //2 so that it catches both errors.
    }
```

## My idea of how to solve the problem/What I've tried otherwise

My plan is to gather a list of all the `NumberFormatException` indices (`i`) thrown in the try. Each time I try to parse the string, an element is added to the `resultsList`. My goal is to then use this theoretical try catch block to obtain the indices of all the exceptions and then remove them from the `resultsList` if they threw an error. TLDR; Right now the above code prints out 0 and I want it to print out 0 and 2. Basically, Instead of having nested try catch blocks I use list comprehension and Exception handling indicies with i to remove the error results and only keep the good ones. I don't know if this is possible hence this question. I've looked at the "better ways to implement nested try catch blocks" question however it wasn't useful to me because It provided a solution in delphi and I didn't understand exactly how it worked or if it even worked the way I want mine to work. I at first thought the finally block might be what I needed but that only runs after the catch is executed or if there is no exception, after the try. I need something that postpones the catch block untill the try is complete and I can't think of/find anything that does that.

## What are you, crazy?

right now you may be asking, what the hell is the point of this? Well imagine if you had the above problem but instead of two ways to parse the string you had 10 or 100. Pretty quickly, exception handling that with nested try catch blocks would be nigh impossible. I've seen solutions where the catch block calls a custom exception method that then at least takes care of the bad formatting. It looked like this:

```
try{
//bad code
}
catch{
    trysomethingelse();
}
trysomethingelse(){
//equally bad code
catch{
//ya done screwed up son
}
}
```

However I'm not satisfied because it means that you need a million different method names just to potentially handle one error. Imagine the error would always be the same you just need to try 100 different string parsing methods. Its always going to be a numberformatException if you're trying to convert a string to a number so why have a million catch blocks just for the same error? I want to try to do this with one theoretical catch block that specifies one error that happens many times over in the try block.

Comment: Just one point: you likely wouldn’t/shouldn’t  try parse a String 100 times in one block.

Comment: If an exception occurs, you *can't* just ignore it and keep going. If `Integer.parseInt` throws an exception, it *doesn't return anything*. Not even `null`. You have nothing to append to your list.

Comment: You can use a bunch of little `try`/`catch` constructs with the same or similar code in each `catch`, but it is a fundamental Java behavior that when an exception is thrown, it breaks the current control flow and goes to the innermost applicable `catch` or `finally`.  That's pretty much the defining characteristic of an exception, in fact.

Comment: It would be simpler to just always use `double` (or `BigDecimal`) instead of trying to parse multiple types of number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You build a list/array of parsers, then iterate that list, catching exception for each.

With Java 8 method references, this is real easy. First, define a `Parser` functional interface that allows exceptions to be thrown:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Parser {
    Object parse(String text) throws Exception;
}
```

Next, build your array of parsers to try:

```
Parser[] parsers = {
        Integer::valueOf,
        Double::valueOf,
        BigInteger::new,
        BigDecimal::new
};
```

Finally, try them one at a time:

```
String text = "45.8";

Object[] results = new Object[parsers.length];
for (int i = 0; i < parsers.length; i++) {
    try {
        results[i] = parsers[i].parse(text);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        results[i] = e;
    }
}
```

Now you can go through the results:

```
for (Object result : results) {
    if (result instanceof Exception)
        System.out.println("Error: " + result);
    else
        System.out.println("Parsed as " + result.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + result);
}
```

*Output*

```
Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "45.8"
Parsed as Double: 45.8
Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "45.8"
Parsed as BigDecimal: 45.8
```

Or put the parsed objects and the exceptions into two different lists. Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
 interface Parser {
       Number parse(String);
 }

 class IntegerParser implements Parser {
    @Override
    public Number parse(String) {
         // implementation here
    }
 }
 class FloatParser implements Parser {
 }

 List<Parser> parsers = asList(new FloatParser(), new IntegerParser(), ...);
 Number result = null;
 List<NumberFormatException> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
 for (Parser parser : parsers) {
     try {
         result = parser.parse(stringToParse);
         break;
     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         exceptions.add(e);
     }
 }
 if (result != null) {
    // parsed ok with some parser
    // probably discard exceptions
 } else {
    // show exceptions from the list
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void test() {
    final String num = "1.0";
    final ArrayList<Object> listofResults = new ArrayList<>();
    final java.util.function.Function<String, ?>[] parseMethods = new java.util.function.Function[3];
    parseMethods[0] = Integer::parseInt;
    parseMethods[1] = Float::parseFloat;
    parseMethods[2] = Integer::parseInt;
    int[] badIndeces = IntStream.range(0, parseMethods.length).map(i -> {
        try {
            listofResults.add(parseMethods[i].apply(num));
            return -i-1;
        } catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
            return i;
        }
    }).filter(i -> i >= 0).toArray();
    for (int element : badIndeces) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```